# How to set the capacity of the ramdisk

Tags: linux, module, ramdisk

I compile the ramdisk as a module in the kernel.Then I want use the cmd :insmod brd rd_size = 10000 to set the capacity of the ramdisk.But it says I give the wrong parameters.
Then I go to see the source code of this module.
static int __init brd_init(void).There is no parameters list.
If I want to set the capacity of the ramdisk,What can I do?

Comment: My kernel version is 3.12.0

Comment: Can you try like `modprobe brd rd_size=10000` or `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ram1 bs=1024 count=1000000` or `mkfs -q /dev/ram1 X` where X is the size in KB.

Answer (score 6):

Try `modprobe brd rd_nr=1 rd_size=1048576 max_part=0`

That should give you one 1G partition at `/dev/ram0`.

Solution referenced from [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=114458) with a code reference [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/block/brd.c?v=3.14)

Comment: More info: `rd_nr` is the number of RAM disks it creates; by default, it creates ram0 through ram15, but specifying 1 just creates ram0.  `rd_size` is the size of the disk in **kilobytes** (1024 bytes per kilobyte).  Parameter documentation can be found in the source code: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/block/brd.c#L330